Docusign 'documentId' tab property usage
From https://www.docusign.com/blog/developers/tabs-deep-dive-anatomy-tab the author writes:
"For now, it’s important to note that the 'documentId' and 'pageNumber' properties are only required if you are not placing your tabs with anchor strings."
The above makes sense if there is only one document to sign. However if multiple documents need to be signed how does this work?
Let's assume that I need two documents signed by someone. I construct the following information to be sent via the Docusign API:
{
    "emailSubject": "Please sign attached doc",
    "emailBlurb": "Info to be signed",
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "documentBase64": "Base64 string",
            "name": "Testfile1.pdf"
        },
        {
            "documentId": "2",
            "documentBase64": "Base64 string",
            "name": "Testfile2.pdf"
        }

    ],
    "recipients": {
        "signers": [
            {
                "email": "abc@test.net",
                "name": "John Doe",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs": {
                    "signHereTabs": [
                        {
                            "anchorString": "[POS_A]",
                            "documentId": "1"
                        },
                            "anchorString": "[POS_B]",
                            "documentId": "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "sent"
}

Before reading the aforementioned documentation I assumed that I could specify the 'documentId' property of the 'signhereTabs' tab, which in turn would mean that the 'anchorstring'
property value of '[POS_A]' would be searched for in the document with 'documentId'=1 and the 'anchorstring' property value of '[POS_B]' would be searched for in the document with 'documentId'=2.
However, As I now understand: the two 'documentId' properties are irrelevant AND both documents are searched for for the two 'anchorstring' property values '[POS_A]' and '[POS_B]'
Is this correct?
Furthermore, what happens if both documents contain the two tags '[POS_A]' and '[POS_B]'?

Good question. I think the docs are wrong--document Id can be important (see below) when anchor text positioning is used.
Please test it and report back!
There are two modes for processing anchor text positioning in an envelope (transaction):

Per Document--the anchor text search is limited to a specific document. (Afaik this is the default)
Per Envelope--all documents in envelope are searched for the anchor text

To change the mode for an account, contact Docusign customer service. (It is not a self-service setting)
If per document, and there's more than one document, the document id becomes important

Thanks @Larry for the info. I'll look into it and report back.
